# WPF TableAdapter update call fails with "Object reference null error"

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dataset, tableadapter

I have a WPF app that has a listbox and 3 textbox fields that are bound from a dataset (which is an Entity Data Model from database).  So, for example, when I click on a customer name in my listbox, the textboxes populate with customer information.  These textboxes are editable.

What I am trying to do is have a save button click event to run a TableAdapter.Update command.  I instantiate a new "Customer" row, and then set those properties with the text from the textboxes.  The problem occurs when I try to run the Update command, and it returns an "Object reference null" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell without any code. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Good point.  Thanks for your reply, but I think I've gotten it working now.